# Wordpress wrap select element with div

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making an e-commerce and on my single product page (working with Woocommerce) i would like to add an icon to the select element at the right (dropdown icon). but i can't do a pseudo class before or after to the select element. So i need to wrap the select element to add it to the class of the div?

The code at the moment:

```
<select id="pa_farbe" class="" name="attribute_pa_farbe" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_farbe" data-show_option_none="yes">
    <option value="">Wählen Sie eine Option</option>
    <option value="gruen" class="attached enabled">Grün</option>
    <option value="kupfer" class="attached enabled">Kupfer</option>
    <option value="lachs" class="attached enabled">Lachs</option>
    <option value="tuerkisblau" class="attached enabled">Türkisblau</option>
    <option value="violett" class="attached enabled">Violett</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you can use css using background to select tag to add dropdown.

Comment: Glad! to hear that my suggestion helped you.